# Multiple definition of functions

Tags: c, multiple-definition-error

I have use 1 header file and 2 code files. One of "multiple definition..." function is duplicate because I use "#ifdef _WIN32 ..." and "#ifdef **unix**...".
I have error "multiple definition..." in "limpaConsola" and "menuInicial".
What is wrong?

kartHead.h

```
    #ifndef kartHead_H
        #define kartHead_H
        void limpaConsola(void);
        void menuInicial(char tipoMenu);
    #endif
```

kartFunc.c

```
    #include "kartHead.h"

    #ifdef _WIN32
        #include <windows.h>
        void limpaConsola(void) {
            HANDLE hOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
            COORD topLeft = {0, 0};
            DWORD dwCount, dwSize;
            CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
            GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hOutput, &csbi);
            dwSize = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;
            FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hOutput, 0x20, dwSize, topLeft, &dwCount);
            FillConsoleOutputAttribute(hOutput, 0x07, dwSize, topLeft, &dwCount);
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOutput, topLeft);
        }
    #endif /* _WIN32 */

    #ifdef __unix__
        #include <stdio.h>
        void limpaConsola(void) {
            printf("\x1B[2J");
        }
    #endif /* __unix__ */

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    bool controlo;
    int opc;    

    void menuInicial(char tipoMenu){
        controlo=1;
        while(controlo){
            limpaConsola();
            ...
        }
    }
```

kart.c

```
#include "kartFunc.c"
void main()
{
    menuInicial('c');
}
```

Comment: never include a .c file, function definitions are once defined in kartFunc.c and again when you included the file in kart.c

Comment: Don't include `kartFunc.c`; include `kartHead.h`

Comment: But in that topic is wrong? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3690/criando-o-seu-pr%C3%B3prio-header-file -- With your suggestion the code is good. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I don't read Portuguese.

Comment: Including a C file is a common rookie error. What you want instead is to either compile kartFunc as a library, and then include the header and link to the library in your main file. OR simply tell the compiler to compile the .c file and include the header.